# How to configure the Fastlane configuration path for the xcode project file?

Tags: fastlane

I'm having problems with the configuration of the fastlane build. But first I need to give some context.

The "fastlane beta" and "fastlane release" commands give errors in the "slack" step Like this:

```
[10:13:20]: -------------------
[10:13:20]: --- Step: slack ---
[10:13:20]: -------------------
[10:13:50]: Exception: Failed to open TCP connection to hooks.slack.com:443 (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known)
[10:13:50]: An error occurred while executing the `error` block:
[10:13:50]: Error pushing Slack message, maybe the integration has no permission to post on this channel? Try removing the channel parameter in your Fastfile, this is usually caused by a misspelled or changed group/channel name or an expired SLACK_URL
```

The command "fastlane gym" is giving me this result:

```
BlueStars-iMac:ios bluestar$ fastlane gym
[✔]  
[09:42:28]: fastlane detected a Gemfile in the current directory
[09:42:28]: However, it seems like you didn't use `bundle exec`
[09:42:28]: To launch fastlane faster, please use
[09:42:28]: 
[09:42:28]: $ bundle exec fastlane gym
[09:42:28]: 
[09:42:28]: Get started using a Gemfile for fastlane https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/ios/setup/#use-a-gemfile
[09:42:29]: Resolving Swift Package Manager dependencies...
[09:42:29]: $ xcodebuild -resolvePackageDependencies -workspace ./Step\ 1\ System.xcworkspace -scheme Step\ 1\ System
[09:42:30]: ▸ Command line invocation:
[09:42:30]: ▸     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -resolvePackageDependencies -workspace "./Step 1 System.xcworkspace" -scheme "Step 1 System"
[09:42:30]: ▸ 2020-05-18 09:42:30.533 xcodebuild[9008:189503]  DTDeviceKit: deviceType from 0cafa1d1eacaf90cfcc1a47ad04e5d3c28e53059 was NULL
[09:42:31]: ▸ resolved source packages: 
[09:42:31]: $ xcodebuild -showBuildSettings -workspace ./Step\ 1\ System.xcworkspace -scheme Step\ 1\ System

+------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|                               Summary for gym 2.148.0                                |
+------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| workspace              | ./Step 1 System.xcworkspace                                 |
| scheme                 | Step 1 System                                               |
| destination            | generic/platform=iOS                                        |
| output_name            | Step 1 System                                               |
| build_path             | /Users/bluestar/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-05-18 |
| clean                  | false                                                       |
| output_directory       | .                                                           |
| silent                 | false                                                       |
| skip_package_ipa       | false                                                       |
| skip_package_pkg       | false                                                       |
| result_bundle          | false                                                       |
| buildlog_path          | ~/Library/Logs/gym                                          |
| skip_profile_detection | false                                                       |
| xcode_path             | /Applications/Xcode.app                                     |
+------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+

[09:42:32]: $ set -o pipefail && xcodebuild -workspace ./Step\ 1\ System.xcworkspace -scheme Step\ 1\ System -destination 'generic/platform=iOS' -archivePath /Users/bluestar/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-05-18/Step\ 1\ System\ 2020-05-18\ 09.42.32.xcarchive archive | tee /Users/bluestar/Library/Logs/gym/Step\ 1\ System-Step\ 1\ System.log | xcpretty
[09:42:36]: ▸ ❌  error: Signing for "Step 1 System" requires a development team. Select a development team in the Signing & Capabilities editor. (in target 'Step 1 System' from project 'Step 1 System')
[09:42:36]: ▸ ** ARCHIVE FAILED **

❌  error: Signing for "Step 1 System" requires a development team. Select a development team in the Signing & Capabilities editor. (in target 'Step 1 System' from project 'Step 1 System')


** ARCHIVE FAILED **
[09:42:36]: Exit status: 65
```

This project was set on another developer's machine and I'm trying to make it work on the project owner's machine.

So I identified a problem in the path to the project file (.xcodeproject) in a configuration file inside the folder "defaultFastfiles". The file "ios.txt" has this GYM_PROJECT and SLACK_URL variables:

```
fastlane_version "2.23.0"

default_platform :ios

platform :ios do
  before_all do |lane, options|
    ENV["GYM_PROJECT"] = "/Users/kristenworkman/dev/code/mobileApp/platforms/ios/!TeamBackslash!.xcodeproject"
    ENV["SLACK_URL"] = "https://hooks.slack.com/services/DFGDF33/5FDG77/sdfsdS7sdfh987928374"
```

So, this folder "kristenworkman" does not exist on the machine 
and should be "bluestars" as follows:

```
ENV["GYM_PROJECT"] = "/Users/bluestars/dev/code/mobileApp/platforms/ios/!TeamBackslash!.xcodeproject"
```

I may be being stupid at this step, but this syntax in the file name "!TeamBackslash!" is confusing me. I don't know if this is a fastlane variable or an environment variable. The actual file name is "Step 1 System.xcodeproject"

So I tried to configure the file with these two versions and none worked:

```
ENV["GYM_PROJECT"] = "/Users/bluestars/dev/code/mobileApp/platforms/ios/Step 1 System.xcodeproject"
```

And:

```
ENV["GYM_PROJECT"] = "/Users/bluestars/dev/code/mobileApp/platforms/ios/Step\ 1\ System.xcodeproject"
```

Another detail about "!TeamBackslash!", It also appears in the "fastlaneInit.sh" file in the following lines:

```
cd fastlane/
echo "----------------------------------------------"
echo "--------COPYING/MODIFYING IOS FASTFILE--------"
echo "----------------------------------------------"

systemBackslash=${sysName// /'\ '}

fastfileIos=${fastfileIos//!TEAM!/$sysName}
fastfileIos=${fastfileIos//!TeamCamel!/$systemSpaceless}
fastfileIos=${fastfileIos//!appID!/$appIDEnding}
fastfileIos=${fastfileIos//!TeamBackslash!/"$systemBackslash"}
echo "$fastfileIos" > Fastfile
```

So I tried to address this "!TeamBackslash!" as a variable before changing the project's file name, but it also doesn't work.

Finally after that context I can ask my two real questions:

1 - Where this variable is !TeamBackslash! should it be defined?
I didn't find a definition of it in the files. Running a search I just found it being used, but I don't know where it is defined.

2 - How should the ENV["GYM_PROJECT"] configuration look?
I imagine the correct thing would be like this:

```
ENV["GYM_PROJECT"] = "/Users/bluestars/dev/code/mobileApp/platforms/ios/!TeamBackslash!.xcodeproject"
```

Am I right?

Sorry for the long question, but the documentation is not helping with these details.